# mongoose: findOneAndUpdate find more complicated expression than _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, insert-update

I want to find a document, that matches some calculated ID and then looks if the timestamp is younger than 15 minutes. If thats the case and a doc is found, I want to update the document with the req.body. Otherwise, if it's older than 15 minutes, or no document is found, I want to create a new document with the req.body.

Now my question is, should I use static findOneAndUpdate method or is it too unflexible for my purpose?
I was using aggregation framework, can it do those type of stuff, like update fields and / or set fields if they are not existant yet?
This is my aggregation pipeline to look for the doc ID and timestamp less than 15 minutes:

```
exports.calcID = function(req,res) {
        console.log("Call aggregation stage..:")        

        Flex.aggregate([        
            {
                $addFields: {
                    subID:  {
                        "$eq": [{"$trunc": {"$divide": ["$_id", 1000000]}}, +req.params.demo_id]                    
                    },
                    rightTime: {
                        "$gte": ["$createdAt", new Date(+new Date()- 60*1000*15)]
                    }
                }
            },      
            {
                "$match": { 
                    subID:true,
                    rightTime:true

                }
            },
            {
                "$sort": {"Timestamp":-1}
            },
            {
                "$limit": 1
            },
            {
                "$project": {subID:0, rightTime:0}
            }
        ]).exec(function(err, flPot) {
            console.log(flPot);
            console.log("Anzahl gefundener Dokumente: ", flPot.length)      
            if (flPot.length == 0) {
                res.end("Keine Dokumente juenger 15 Minuten gefunden!")
                var flex = new FlexPotenzial(req.body);     
                flex.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {              
                    console.log("Instanz FlexPotenzial in Datenbank erzeugt!");
                    res.status(200);
                    res.json({ message: 'FlexPotenzial-Instance created in datbase!\n', flex });
                }
                })
            }
            else if (flPot.lengh!==0) {
                    flPot.Timestamp = req.body.Timestamp;
                    flPot.aktThErzeugungsleistungWaerme = req.body.aktThErzeugungsleistungWaerme;
                    flPot.aktThNachfrageleistungWaerme = req.body.aktThNachfrageleistungWaerme;
                    flPot.aktThErzeugungsleistungGas = req.body.aktThErzeugungsleistungGas;
                    flPot.aktThNachfrageleistungGas = req.body.aktThNachfrageleistungGas;
                    flPot.aktLeistungsuntergrenze = req.body.aktLeistungsuntergrenze;
                    flPot.aktLeistungsobergrenze = req.body.aktLeistungsobergrenze;
                    flPot.BrennRohstoffbezug = req.body.BrennRohstoffbezug;
                    flPot.Produktstrom = req.body.Produktstrom;
                    flPot.Dummy1 = req.body.Dummy1;
                    flPot.Dummy2 = req.body.Dummy2;
                    flPot.Dummy3 = req.body.Dummy3;
                    flPot.Dummy4 = req.body.Dummy4;

                    flPot.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(400);
                            res.send(err);
                        }
                        else {              
                            console.log("FlexPotenzial aggregierte Daten in Datenbank aktualisiert!");
                            res.status(200);
                            res.json({ message: 'FlexPotenzial-Instance aggregated data updated!\n', flex });
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't know whats the best approach here and how to check after docs are found or not, how to update the fields, and if no docs are found, how to create new docs in aggregation or in a separate function then...

Comment: Aggregation is read-only. Calculate timestamp upfront as `new Date() - 15 minutes`, then use it in the filter with `$gte` condition. Use upserts to insert new document when no match found, or update the matched one in a single query.

Comment: ok but how can I match a given ID from the url parametre to match my _id in the doc, after it was divided by 1000000? And besides that, is it possible to intermix found documents from aggregation framework with static find() methods to process the documents further? e.g I have a result variable from aggregation framework, then use result.findOneAndUpdate() method on it? Possible?

Comment: Multiply the id from request and do exact match. To the rest of the comment - possible, but is something opposite to the "best approach" you asked.

Comment: why multiply? I dont understand what that effects..?

Comment: When you multiply you do it once per request and can benefit from indexes. When you divide you do it once per document per request and cannot use indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you divide your stored ID to get a range of IDs. Why not do that in a query :

```
const minID = req.params.demo_id * 1000000;
const maxID = (req.params.demo_id + 1) * 1000000;
const fifteenMinutesAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 15*3600*1000)
Flex.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: { $gte: minID, $lt: maxID },
  createdAt: { $gte: fifteenMinutesAgo }
}, { $set: req.body })
```

Of course, you should sanitize your inputs, not just throw `req.body` in.

If the ID calculation is more complicated than what you put in this snippet, consider storing it in your document.

Comment: wow thanks, I couldn't come up with that one, I remember I was thinking about this solution once, no idea why I couldn't remember it ;). One more question, if I want to set individual fields, can I just do it with the body of the json document? e.g {$set: {name: req.body.name},{field2: req.body.field2}} and so on? btw... 15 mins ago is 1000*60*15

Comment: You're welcome ! I put `req.body` for the sake of simplicity, but yes, you can have a more complex `$set`. Be careful how you place the brackets, though : ` { $set: { name: req.body.name, field2: req.body.field2 } }`